# Add jQuery elements to object?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I want to create an object to store jQuery objects.
Here is my code so far:

```
var tabList = $();

function addTab(){
    console.log($(this));
    var theConcept = 'conceptName';
    var $tab = $('<li />');
    $tab.append('<a>' + theConcept + '</a>').data("concept", theConcept);
    $tab.append('<span class="closeTab">Close</span>');
    console.log($tab);
    tabList.push($tab);
    console.log(tabList);
}
```

When I log the tabList, it outputs: [>e.fn.e.i]

What I'm really trying to do have an array or object that I can add and remove elements from and then refresh the DOM based on this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add elements to a jQuery object. `tabList = tabList.add($tab);`

Comment: One more question, it seems that the data is not being added to the `<a>` in my example above. I can't tell why though.

Comment: @talknmime you are adding the data to the `li` not the `a`

Comment: Oh I see. Any idea why only the last item in the tabList has data associated with it.